# Most effective way to display the internet light-on-dark?

Tags: firefox, internet, web, user-interface

Due to some serious lapse of judgement, most of the internet, this site included >:(, is displayed as black-on-white ­­— which is the way that it makes sense to display printed text — instead of light-on-dark, which is the way that it naturally makes sense to display text on a luminescent screen. I find that staring at a white screen, reading black text, is like staring at a light bulb, and totally abhorrent, not to mention probably damaging to my eyesight.

I have tried various 'night mode' addons for inverting color schemes in firefox, but none of them are really ideal. Has anyone with a similar viewpoint found an effective way to invert the internet's (in general) color scheme without compromising style? How would a web programming expert tackle this problem? Maybe by executing custom css or javascript? I am not an expert, but I am a proficient coder. I simply do not know where to start in this case. Since the internet is made up of rendered documents, I am sure there should be an effective way to save our eyes and display them in a way that is suitable for a display screen, as opposed to a printed page.

Comment: + I think the savings in terms of Wh would be huge earth-wise. Anyone made the computation?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Stylish add-on for Firefox? I think it would suit your needs, there's a lot of user made CSS files available for it, including all Stack Exchange websites. If you wish you can make CSS by yourself for any website you want.

Not sure about making custom add-on for whole internet. I feel your problem though. black-on-white designs make my eyes hurt a lot too.

Comment: Hes not really asking for a solution from someone, but a way to tackle a solution from himself. You could edit this to recommend he use stylish to create his own CSS files for websites ;P.

Comment: @Tealkine if there's an existing solution, that's wonderful. I just wanted to say that I'm not necessarily *looking* for an existing solution, I would also be happy with a path to a solution.

Comment: I'm personally using Stylish with custom CSS for websites I visit often. Don't know any better option. If anybody can come up with something better I would gladly start using it too.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Firefox add-on called Blank Your Monitor (BYM) that gives you the ability to change a site to high contrast by using keyboard shortcuts, the default is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>.

The results:

[image]